# Mock domain persisted in unit test even if call to save returns false or null

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

As mentioned in title, I am trying to test if my domain is not being persisted after an error occurs. The code under test is:

```
//domain is created using mockDomain(DomainClass, [...])
domain.someField = newValue
domain.someProperty = invalidValue
if(!domain.hasErrors() && domain.save()) {
    log.info "Saved."
} else {
    //domain.refresh() or domain.discard() does not have a difference and domain still gets persisted after calling these                               
    domain.errors.allErrors.each{
        log.error "Error: $it"          
    }
}
```

and I have something like this in unit tests:

```
def domain = DomainClass.get(domain.id)
assertEquals(oldValue, domain.someField) // but now domain.someField is set to newValue
```

The code above is inside a controller save action. In my unit tests I am using mockDomain(DomainClass) to mock the domain and send it to the save action. So when I set `someProperty` to an `invalidValue` the code correctly goes into the else block, prints errors and save returns null. But despite the fact that I have errors in the domain when I try to assert the value of my domain, I get back all the values which were set on it including `newValue` shown in code sample. I would have expected that if my domain has some errors then it would not be persisted. Could anyone please explain this and how to get my domain not to persist?

Comment: What happens if instead of `DomainClass.get(domain.id)` you call `domain.refresh()`? Or you could wrap the checking code inside `DomainClass.withNewSession { ... }`

Comment: you mean I call refresh or DomainClass.withNewSession in the unit test?

Comment: also fyi I have tried to use DomainClass.withTransaction in controller but then this does not work with unit tests

Comment: If `withNewSession` doesn't work (I use the `HibernateTestMixin` for all testing nowadays and it does work there), then do try `domain.refresh()` before checking if the properties have their old values. `.get()` will fetch an item from cache while `refresh()` should explicitly avoid it.